# NoClassDefFoundException due to some classes of library project are missing in debug build and exist in release build

Tags: android

My App is getting crash with NoClassDefFoundException  in debug build and working fine with release build.
I decompiled the both apks and found the that some of the class files from cordova library were missing in the debug apk.

The strange thing is this crash is happening on 4.4 & below devices and working fine inabove 4.4.

I dont have any clue how it is workin in higher sdk versions. Please help.

Comment: maybe some classes where integrated in newer SDK Versions?

Comment: Did you use multidex? Below `4.4` (20), you need to use support library multidex https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle

Comment: @Kevinrob - you are right its issue with multidex. Thanks for your prompt help.

Answer (score 0):

Its issue with Multidex, For below 4.4 devices we need to add support library of multidex.